# Button on click not perform segue method.and occur this type of error

Tags: objective-c, iphone, segue

if i am call `perform segue` method on `button click`.that this type error occur.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[bparty setNdetail:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17da33c0'

Here is the code:

```
 -(IBAction)btn_serch:(id)sender { 
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bparty" sender:self]; 
 }
```

how to solve..tell me

Comment: post ur code here. this types of errors occur when the method setNdetail is not defined.

Comment: - (IBAction)btn_serch:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bparty" sender:self];

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method called `prepareForSegue`
where bparty is the segue identifier in storyboard
and `DetailViewController` is the page where u will goto.

also dont forget to import the DetailViewController(viewcontroller in ur .m file)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        DetailViewController *sendDetails = segue.destinationViewController;

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"bparty"])
        {
        //here ur perfor an action
        //ex [self.navigationController pushViewController:sendDetails animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: then use a `didSelectRowAtIndex` method of tableView Cell.
Woh without button bhi chalega... u only need to use
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bparty" sender:self];`
whenever u use the above statement it needs to go along with prepareForSegue method